# (C#,WPF) Save a ResourceDictionary locally

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

everyone!

I post a request for help here because I'm blocked.

I made a translation system using Resource Dictionaries for keys and values. Nothing to complicate.

Except now I would like to save my Dictionaries locally, (at the launch of the software) so on the disk in a .XAML file.

The problem is that I can't find a way to save them

Here is a resource dictionary that I would like to save:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<!-- General -->
<sys:String x:Key="LanguageName">en</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="LanguageDisplayName">English</sys:String></ResourceDictionary>
```

Thanks & have a good day!
And sorry for my approximate English, I am French :x

Comment: you should keep them in the dll. the xaml has been compiled into a binary form

Comment: I would like to save it on disk, so that users can edit translations, there is no way? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can write files to disk.
And yes you can then later read them back in to re-create a resource dictionary.

I'm not clear how the user receives what you're showing us.

If it's as a compiled resource dictionary you can instantiate that and then write it to disk using XamlWriter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Or you could read a "flat" uncompiled xaml file off a web server and save it to appdata.

An odd thing about resource dictionaries.

The same syntax you use to merge a resource dictionary will work with an uncompiled .xaml file.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx#Loading_a_Flat_File_as_a_Resource_Dictionary

You can alternatively xamlreader.load() a flat .xaml file and create a resource dictionary in memory that you then merge in code.

You can manipulate uncompiled xaml files as strings or treat them as xml.
Some of the samples in the link do that.

And you can receive a resource dictionary as a string from a service and xamlreader.parse() that into a resource dictionary in memory. That you can then merge in code.

BTW

Your English seems fine to me.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I can now save the dictionaries thanks to XamlWriter, but there is a slight problem (Which is not annoying if I can't fix it), this problem is that the XamlWriter.Save function returns the Xaml code well but on a single line, the code is not indented. Do you have a solution? Thank you ;)

Comment: Why would indentation matter?

Comment: it's not very important, but.... I would still like the indentation (if it's possible and doesn't consume a lot of performance). Because I was doing the save of the dictionary so that users could modify the values in the software files, and if the file is not indented, it's not practical :x But if it's not possible it's not a problem! Thank you.

Comment: You could try xml formatting. That can indent xml and an rd is xml. Something like xdocument.parse(string).tostring(). Where string is your resourcedictionary read as a string.

Comment: Great! Thank you the indentation works. And I know I'm annoying but would you have any idea how to preserve the comments and the order of values? Because my file is saved in the wrong order and the comments have disappeared.

Comment: You'd have to give them the uncompiled version to retain comments. You could maybe order by x:key.

Comment: Okay, I didn't figure out how to do it. But it doesn't matter, I managed to do what I still wanted, thank you and have a good day!